# Combinatorics - Dispositions with repetitions?

Tags: combinatorics

I was trying to solve the following exercise:

"How many numbers made up of 6 figures can be generated, keeping in mind that they must contain number 2 exactly two times, number 1 exactly two times and none of the figures is 0?"

The order of figuers clearly matters, so I immediatly thought of dispositions. Moreover, figures can be repeated. But I am not able to use the information "number 2 appears exactly two times, number 1 appears exactly two times". How can I deal with this variable which determines the occurences of 1 and 2?

The correct answer is 4410, but I don't have any demostration. Is my idea of working with dispositions with repetitions correct? Is there any closed formula which allow me to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pick which two positions are occupied by $2$'s and which two of the remaining positions are occupied by $1$'s.  Then from left-to-right pick which number occupies each remaining space.  $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\cdot 7\cdot 7=4410$.  As an aside, the term "disposition" is not what is commonly used in English to describe this type of object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What do you call In English the combinatorial object which allows you to calculate the set of injective functions from A to B, where |A|=k and |B|=n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want that your number had three groups: a group of two $2$'s, a group of two $1$'s and a group of two numbers from the set $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Then, depending on the third group, you have two cases: that the two "figures" of the group three will be equal or different.

We will name the three groups respectively $A,B$ and $C$. One way to do it is the following.

**Case 1, the figures of the group $C$ are equal**: then you want to count the different number of ways to order the set of figures $\{1,1,2,2,c,c\}$ where $c$ are the figures of the set $C$.

We knows than in a set of $n$ different objects there are $n!$ different ways to order them in a line, what is called as permutations. Suppose than our objects are all different, then because we have $6$ different figures we can order them in $6!=6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=720$ different ways.

Now, because equal figures can be swapped of positions but the number will be the same, we must divide the total possible $720$ arrangements by $2$. Because this happen for the three groups of figures then we have $720/(2\cdot2\cdot 2)=90$. And because $c$ can have seven different values then the total of ways to order $\{1,1,2,2,c,c\}$ is $90\cdot 7=630$.

**Case 2, the figures of the group $C$ are different**: this is very similar to the first case but this time we must divide $720$ only by $4$ because we only need two groups with two elements. Then, by the moment, the ways to order $\{1,1,2,2,c,d\}$ is $720/4=180$. But now we must multiply this quantity by the different groups $C$ we can have from $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ where both figures are different.

In combinatorics this count is done using what is called *combinations*, the number of ways to get different unordered groups of elements from a set of $n$ different elements taken in groups of $k$ is

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

In our case is $\binom{7}{2}=\frac{7\cdot 6}{2}=21$. Hence the total number of ways to order the elements of the case 2 are $180\cdot 21=3780$

---

Finally, if we add the numbers of ways of case 1 and 2 we have the final result: $$630+3780=4410$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer has been very thorough. I could envisage that I had to distinguish two different cases, but I got stuck because I was trying to use the wrong formula. So, these are permutations with repetitions, aren't they?

Comment: We can take the two cases together and just think the third group as permutations with repetitions, that is, $7^2$.